# Сортировка вещественного массива с ошибкой C++

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, float

В коде после компиляции в отсортированном массиве стабильно вторым элементом выдает число -4.22017е+....
Массив вещественных чисел. Я не понимаю, как это исправить, уже и меняла значение всех переменных на флоат, дабл -- все равно. 
Заполнение массива:

```
cout << "Введите кол-во элементов: ";
cin >> n;
float* mass = new float[n];
mass[0] = (rand() % 101 - 50) / 10.0;
imax = mass[0];
dd = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    mass[i] = (rand() % 101 - 50) / 10.0;
```

Вывод исходного массива:

```
cout << "Исходный массив: ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << mass[i] << " ";
    if (max < mass[i])
    {
        max = mass[i];
        imax = i;
    }
}   
cout << endl;
```

Вывод отсортированного:

```
    {
    for (int r = 0; r <= n - 1; r++)
    {
        if (abs(mass[r]) < abs(mass[r + 1]))
        {
            temp = mass[r];
            mass[r] = mass[r + 1];
            mass[r + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    }
    cout << "Отсортированный массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << mass[i] << " ";
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум по тем огрызкам, что вы предоставили (в данном случае полной реализации сортировки нет - самого опасного в смысле ошибок места) -

```
 for (int r = 0; r <= n - 1; r++)
 {
    if (abs(mass[r]) < abs(mass[r + 1]))
    ...
```

При `r == n-1` вы обращаетесь в элементу массива `mass[n]`, который находится *за пределами* вашего массива.

Все, как минимум - неопределенное поведение. Вам не повезло - краха программы не было...

P.S. Просто интересна ваша логика - почему вы не стали проверять свой алгоритм сортировки и начали менять `float` на `double`?...

Comment: Потому что так посоветовала преподаватель :)